# Electron - globalShortcut not listening all event

Tags: javascript, electron, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently working on an application where an user can't close or switch the window (for security).

When i try to register an event like Ctrl+Alt+Delete, the system trigger it, but not my application. At least, i want that event like Alt+Tab, Alt+F4, Ctrl+Alt+Delete can't be triggered by the system for blocking the window's close or the switch window.

Anyone have an idea ?

```
globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+Alt+Delete", () => {
  console.log("CommandOrControl+Alt+Delete triggered")
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Documentation explains it:

*"When the accelerator is already taken by other applications, this call will silently fail. This behavior is intended by operating systems, since they don't want applications to fight for global shortcuts."*

I think those shortcuts are reserved for the OS (Windows). That's why you can "listen" it, because are silenced.

Source: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/global-shortcut